# Creating .fxo shader file using fxc.exe

Tags: c++, shader, directx-11, precompiling

Does anybody know how to compile a single file containing various shaders (PixelShader, VertexShader, GeometryShader) using the fxc.exe tool provided by the DirectX 11 SDK?

The shader is used to create a tesselation-effect in a C++ programmed Enviroment:

The result should be a .fxo shader File.

Thx in advance :)

Comment: Could you not just run it multiple time for each type of shader?

Comment: Mhh maybe, i did not thought of that... But the question is how many Times do i have to rerun it ... :/

Comment: I normally like to put each shader in its own file, makes it easier to find when you need to find it. But you only need to run it 3 times for each shader (PS, VS, GS)

Comment: Hey thx alot! Just to clarify things up, could pls be so kind and give me the excact parameters/command line u r using?

Comment: I now use the built in builder for VS2013, but here is an old one I found `"D:\Library\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Utilities\bin\x86\fxc" /Fc /Od /Zi /T fx_5_0 /Fo "%(RelativeDir)\%(Filename).fxo" "%(FullPath)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run the compiler separately for each effect source file (one source file per effect, including the various shaders and helper routines). There will be a separate shader object file for each effect, similarly. The command line depends on what you actually want to compile but something like this:

```
fxc.exe /T ps_2_0 /nologo /E main /Fo"Effect.fxo" "Effect.fx"
```

or

```
fxc.exe /T fx_4_0 /nologo /Fo"Effect.fxo" "Effect.fx"
```